# Lone humanoid wanders a hostile, frozen ship; befriends an alien with a lemon-shaped head

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to recall the name of a novel, approximately 3 to 5 years old, where the plot follows a lone humanoid as she awakens on a huge, hostile, frozen ship.  Parts of the ship are cold so she has to run through them.  She makes some friends on her trip to the command section of the ship.  For some reason I recall one of her alien friends has a lemon shaped head.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/152708/edit) any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Probably not [this guy.](http://theboxofme.wikia.com/wiki/Lemon_Head_the_Alien)